# gitlab-runner broken in CI, works manually - Debian release-upgrade at fault?

Tags: linux, debian, gitlab-ci-runner

Some time ago, I had set up a gitlab-runner on a Debian 9 server. All was well. CI ran and it ran successfully. Now, 11 months after the last test had been run, I was instructed to add a feature to the project and the first thing I did was re-run old tests.

They failed, going from "no problem" to "no worky at all" in 11 months. The only thing that I gave significance to was a distribution-upgrade to Debian 10.

No worky - running locally under gitlab-runner's service-account:

```
/tmp/projektv$ sudo -u gitlab-runner /usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner   exec shell run_tests
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=25578 revision=1564076b version=12.4.0
Running with gitlab-runner 12.4.0 (1564076b)
Using Shell executor...
Running on simsrv15...
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
FATAL: exit status 1
```

Automatic jobs (when pushing commits) on the webUI look the same. Same outcome with gitlab-runner versions 12.0 and 12.3. No change with new registration.

Works when run locally with my personal user-account:

```
/tmp/project$ /usr/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner exec shell run_tests
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=23331 revision=1564076b version=12.4.0
Running with gitlab-runner 12.4.0 (1564076b)
Using Shell executor...
Running on simsrv15...
Fetching changes...
....
OK
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('file:memorydb_default?mode=memory&cache=shared')...
Job succeeded
```

Running the faulty job with `--debug` or even `strace` did not reveal anything especially interesting to me. https://pastebin.com/8j8eQAHB

Running the same job from a different runner, newly set up on a Debian 9 system, works perfectly.

Comment: it could be a problem of git-lab. `gitlab-runner exec` was deprecated, un-deprecated, but still not 100% working. Check gitlab documentation

Comment: Thanks. Would that also explain, why the automatic jobs assigned from the gitlab-server's CI are not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that running `strace -f` automatically attaches to spawned children. As I had seen that forking was one of the last things that the runner did, I tried that. And look what I found:

```
[pid 88504] execve("/usr/bin/clear_console", ["/usr/bin/clear_console", "-q"], 0x564cc4bbf1c0 /* 19 vars */) = 0
```

`clear_console`, eh? Armed with new knowledge, google gave me this:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4559

Fun thing: Debian 9 also has `clear_console` in the `.bash_logout`, where it does not crash the runner....